# php require_once includes files relative to file instead of working directory

Tags: php, include-path, require-once, set-include-path

I have some problems with including files relatively. The problem isn't that require_once can't find a file, but the fact that it CAN find a file in a place where the file isn't. I have stripped down the problem to three small classes.

So this is my dir structure:

```
public_html/
    index.php
    commands/
        CommandFactory.php
        account/
            Status.php
```

index.php:

```
require_once 'commands/CommandFactory.php';

$factory = new CommandFactory();
```

CommandFactory.php:

```
    class CommandFactory{

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo getcwd() . '<br/>'; //xxx\public_html (which is good, this is where index.php is
        //require_once 'account/Status.php'; // This works as expected
        require_once 'account/Status.php'; // This ALSO works, but it shouldn't

        $status = new Status(); // This works, though it shouldn't. 
    }
}
```

I have tested by moving the CommandFactory to a different dir, which solves the problem. However, I cannot understand why the file can be included. It shouldn't include Status, relative from the CommandFactory, it should be relative from index.php. I added the current working dir, to see what goes wrong, but i can't figure it out. Anybody knows how and why this works?

Comment: Can the one who downvoted my question explain why?

Comment: If u do a require the path is relative to the current file. Not the index, anyway including a file inside a class is actualy not a good practise. You definitely should look into autoloading your classes

Comment: "If u do a require the path is relative to the current file." This is not right." And I know what i'm doing in OOP. Also, if it was relative to the current file, why does "commands/account/Status.php" also work?

Comment: `Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing. The include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error` [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: Goddammit, you're right. I wish i'd seen that sooner. You should make that the answer, so i can accept it :) Thanks for mentioning autoloading classes. I know when and why to use them, which is not in my current project (I always require_once outside of classes, except in this one, because the class i'm loading is dynamic), but others might find it interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the php.net site :

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given,
>   the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the
>   include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own
>   directory and the current working directory before failing. The
>   include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this
>   is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: Thank you :) Haha i'd rather have that it was stricter though.

Comment: No problem. I like to place __DIR__ before every include/require myself tough

Comment: Well, exaclty because of __DIR__ I thought PHP never included classes relative to relative paths. But i should have tended to php.net.